Cloud Messaging not on Google Console Library
I'm using NodeJS for my backend and React Native Expo for my frontend. I'm trying to work with FCM, but when I try to send notifications with my backend, this error shows up:
FirebaseMessagingError: An error occurred when trying to authenticate to the FCM servers. Make sure the credential used to authenticate this SDK has the proper permissions
This is my code:
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("../serviceaccountkey.json");
const User = require('../models/user');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});

/**
 * Send a push notification to a user identified by their userId.
 * @param {string} userId - The user's ID to send the notification to.
 * @param {string} message - The message content of the notification.
 * @returns {Promise<string>} - Promise resolving to the notification ID if successful.
 */
async function sendPushNotification(userId, message) {
  try {
    // Fetch user's FCM token
    const userFCMToken = await getUserFCMToken(userId);

    if (userFCMToken) {
      // Construct payload for FCM message
      const payload = {
        notification: {
          title: "New Message",
          body: message.toString(),
        },
      };

      // Send FCM message
      const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(userFCMToken, payload);
      console.log("Notification sent successfully:", response);
      return response.messageId; // Return notification ID or status
    } else {
      console.error(`User with ID ${userId} does not have a registered FCM token.`);
      return null;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error sending push notification:", error);
    throw error; // Throw error for handling in caller function
  }
}

/**
 * Fetches the Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) token for a user.
 * @param {string} userId - The ID of the user to fetch the FCM token for.
 * @returns {Promise<string|null>} - Promise resolving to the user's FCM token or null if not found.
 */
async function getUserFCMToken(userId) {
  try {
    // Fetch user data from the database based on userId
    const user = await User.findById(userId);

    if (!user) {
      console.error(`User with ID ${userId} not found.`);
      return null;
    }

    // Extract FCM token from user data
    const fcmToken = user.pushToken;

    if (!fcmToken) {
      console.error(`User with ID ${userId} does not have a registered FCM token.`);
      return null;
    }

    return fcmToken;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching FCM token:', error);
    throw error; // Throw error for handling in caller function
  }
}

module.exports = { sendPushNotification };


I already did the HTTP v1, but I can't enable the cloud messaging because it's not in on the Google console library. When I try to use the expo notification tool it works.

the roles for the service account is all good too.
